# How to access the internet on Ubuntu 12.10 armhf

Tags: arm

- How will I go about connecting to wireless internet with Ubuntu
  12.10 armhf?
- How to install the Chromium browser?

Comment: Are you requesting for the steps on connecting to a wireless or you have difficulties connecting to via wireless?

Comment: I am really asking for some sort of easy to follow step by step guide sort of thing :-) Whatever you can do. One thing to keep in mind is that Ubuntu isn't displaying on my screen correctly as it is to zoomed in for some reason. Therefor, I have no way to access the toolbar. If you have any idea for a solution to that problem, look at my other questions and you can answer it there.